# Sorting dataframe contents based on last column values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort and display the contents of a file. The code I have does not produce the expected output. I have set **ascending=True** or **ascending=False** but it still does not work. Thank in advance.

sampledata.txt # Source file

```
 ADS43   11.468   02:45
982AS2S   5.657   02:45
K72KSU3  -3.398   02:45
 JJS7AS   3.238   02:45
 LO92SA   2.221   02:45
 22SA8A  -1.931   02:45
 ADS43   11.468   03:00
982AS2S  -5.657   03:00
K72KSU3   3.398   03:00
 JJS7AS  -2.238   03:00
 LO92SA   7.221   03:00
 111AS2 -10.756   03:00
 P352AS  -1.912   03:30
982AS2S -12.595   03:30
K72KSU3  -9.153   03:30
 JJS7AS  12.238   03:30
 LO92SA  17.221   03:30
 111AS2 -13.756   03:30
```

Current Code: #output is not properly sorted based on the last column values

```
data = {}
for row in open('sampledata.txt'):
    cols = row.rstrip().split()
    if cols[2] not in data:
        data[cols[2]] = {}
    data[cols[2]][cols[0]] = cols[1]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = df.sort_values(by=[df.columns[-1]], ascending=False)
print (df2)
```

Current Output: #- Based on sampledata.txt

```
          02:45    03:00    03:30
LO92SA    2.221    7.221   17.221
JJS7AS    3.238   -2.238   12.238
K72KSU3  -3.398    3.398   -9.153
111AS2      NaN  -10.756  -13.756
982AS2S   5.657   -5.657  -12.595
P352AS      NaN      NaN   -1.912
ADS43    11.468   11.468      NaN
22SA8A   -1.931      NaN      NaN
```

Intended Output: #- sorted based on the last column from largest to smallest

```
          02:45    03:00    03:30
LO92SA    2.221    7.221   17.221
JJS7AS    3.238   -2.238   12.238
P352AS      NaN      NaN   -1.912
K72KSU3  -3.398    3.398   -9.153
982AS2S   5.657   -5.657  -12.595
111AS2      NaN  -10.756  -13.756
ADS43    11.468   11.468      NaN
22SA8A   -1.931      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your "current" output where there are `nan`s interspersed in the third column. I thought the issue you were having is that it doesn't sort properly due to being strings rather than integers (this is due to the way you read your data frame) but it doesn't look like that.

Comment: Sorry, I made the correction now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've executed your code near-verbatim and don't receive the error you report.

```
data = {}
for row in ''' ADS43   11.468   02:45
982AS2S   5.657   02:45
K72KSU3  -3.398   02:45
 JJS7AS   3.238   02:45
 LO92SA   2.221   02:45
 22SA8A  -1.931   02:45
 ADS43   11.468   03:00
982AS2S  -5.657   03:00
K72KSU3   3.398   03:00
 JJS7AS  -2.238   03:00
 LO92SA   7.221   03:00
 111AS2 -10.756   03:00
 P352AS  -1.912   03:30
982AS2S -12.595   03:30
K72KSU3  -9.153   03:30
 JJS7AS  12.238   03:30
 LO92SA  17.221   03:30
 111AS2 -13.756   03:30'''.split('\n'):
    cols = row.rstrip().split()
    if cols[2] not in data:
        data[cols[2]] = {}
    data[cols[2]][cols[0]] = cols[1]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.sort_values(by=df.columns[-1], ascending=True)
```

That yields this (mis-sorted) data frame but the problem with the sort here is not the same problem as that which you report in your OP (as of [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76980315/1)), which seems merely to be the unsorted version of `df`. The aetiology of the issue is that the data are being sorted as strings and not as numbers.

```
          02:45    03:00    03:30
P352AS      NaN      NaN   -1.912
982AS2S   5.657   -5.657  -12.595
111AS2      NaN  -10.756  -13.756
K72KSU3  -3.398    3.398   -9.153
JJS7AS    3.238   -2.238   12.238
LO92SA    2.221    7.221   17.221
ADS43    11.468   11.468      NaN
22SA8A   -1.931      NaN      NaN
```

---

I think a proper way to solve this problem would be just to run the following. It loads the long form data in numeric format and then pivots (I just prefer `stack` and `unstack`) the data into position.

```
df0 = pd.read_csv(YOUR_FILE, sep='\s+', header=None, index_col=0)
d = df0.set_index(2, append=True)[1].unstack()  # gets rid of multi-index and names
d.columns.name = None
d.index.name = None
d.sort_values(by=d.columns[-1], ascending=False)
```

That yields what you seem to want:

```
          02:45   03:00   03:30
LO92SA    2.221   7.221  17.221
JJS7AS    3.238  -2.238  12.238
P352AS      NaN     NaN  -1.912
K72KSU3  -3.398   3.398  -9.153
982AS2S   5.657  -5.657 -12.595
111AS2      NaN -10.756 -13.756
22SA8A   -1.931     NaN     NaN
ADS43    11.468  11.468     NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
(dfe:=df.pivot(index=0, columns=2, values=1)).sort_values(by=dfe.columns[-1], ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
2         02:45   03:00   03:30
0                              
LO92SA    2.221   7.221  17.221
JJS7AS    3.238  -2.238  12.238
P352AS      NaN     NaN  -1.912
K72KSU3  -3.398   3.398  -9.153
982AS2S   5.657  -5.657 -12.595
111AS2      NaN -10.756 -13.756
22SA8A   -1.931     NaN     NaN
ADS43    11.468  11.468     NaN
```

Comment: Probably there should be `dfe = pd.read_csv("sample.txt", sep=r"\s+", engine="python", header=None)` to give OP an example how to load the data.

Comment: The OP already has a method for loading the data. If you execute the code they provided directly (wrap the data into a list string rows and replace the `open` in the for loop) I don't think this is reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is the problem of the data type of the last column. When you convert the last column into float, the problem will be solved.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in open(r'sampledata.txt'):
    cols = row.rstrip().split()
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(cols).T], ignore_index=True)
df = pd.pivot(data=df, index=0, columns=2)
df.columns = [col[1] for col in df.columns.values]
df[df.columns[-1]] = df[df.columns[-1]].astype(float)
print(df.sort_values(df1.columns[-1], ascending=False))
```

The result is as follows：

```
       02:45    03:00   03:30
0           
LO92SA  2.221   7.221   17.221
JJS7AS  3.238   -2.238  12.238
P352AS  NaN     NaN     -1.912
K72KSU3 -3.398  3.398   -9.153
982AS2S 5.657   -5.657  -12.595
111AS2  NaN     -10.756 -13.756
22SA8A  -1.931  NaN     NaN
ADS43   11.468  11.468  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Performing data wrangling (e.g. pivot) with raw python is usually somewhat messy. Better alternatives have been mentioned.

However, the actual problem of not being able to sort properly by the last column comes down to a simple type conversion:

```
data = {}
for row in open('sampledata.txt'):
    cols = row.rstrip().split()
    if cols[2] not in data:
        data[cols[2]] = {}
    data[cols[2]][cols[0]] = float(cols[1]) ## <<< convert str to float

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = df.sort_values(by=[df.columns[-1]], ascending=False)
print (df2)
```

This should produce the expected result.